# Initiate Admin Authentication using Amazon Cognito in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-cognito

I am new to Cognito services and I am trying to log in by creating a user in my UserPool using admin_initiate_auth. The problem is that I am getting a SystemStackError (stack level too deep) error when I send request from the postman.  Please find the code as below

```
  resp = client.admin_initiate_auth(
  auth_flow: 'ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH',
  user_pool_id: 'ap-south-1_tE3SXXXX',
  client_id: '12345XXXXXXX',
  auth_parameters: {
    USERNAME: 'some_name',
    PASSWORD: 'Dumy12@#'
  }
)
```

Comment: The code is written in controller#index and I am using a GET request. Doesn't know if that matters.

Comment: Also, This problem is only coming when I am using rails. If I use simple ruby, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was coming while rendering the response as json. Removing the render clears the error.